# 2 shift operations in MIPS

Tags: mips

The syntax for sll and srl is:

`sll $s0,$s1,n` (n is an integer, for example `sll $s0,$s1,3`)

`srl $s0,$s1,n` (n is an integer, for example `srl $s0,$s1,3`)

I wonder if I can substitute $n$ for a register.

For instance:

```
sll $s0,$s1,$s2
```

I'm sorry, I'm a newbie to MIPS.

Comment: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you're looking for are `sllv`/`srlv` et al. For example, `sllv $s0,$s1,$s2`

And as always when having questions regarding the MIPS instruction set, consult *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*.

Comment: Does it mean that there's no way for the register to replace the integer?

Comment: I think you misread my answer. _"The instructions you're looking for are sllv/srlv et al."_ So yes, you can shift by a register-specified amount.

Comment: To clarify: `sllv`, `srlv` are different instructions than `sll`, `srl`.